# How to use gamma family in GLMMTMB

Tags: r, statistics, glm, gamma-distribution, glmmtmb

I have a variable called "duration_bout" which corresponds to a duration in seconds. Here's what the distribution looks like:

[image: distribution]

It looks like a Poisson distribution, but my durations are a continuous variable. If I transform my data to integers, Poisson fits rather well: [image: glmmTMB model]

I think what I really have here is rather a gamma distribution, but I can't figure out how to use this family in glmmTMB! Several questions:

- family=gamma() asks me to define an "x" parameter; what is it?
- How come Poisson model fits? How correct is it to tranform my data to integers in order to use it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with capital `g` e.g. `Gamma`

Comment: Tried already, it is giving me this error: "Warning in (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  : NA/NaN function evaluation" even though none of my variables contain empty data

Comment: its giving a *Warning* not an *error*. But you could try to help the optimiser with a log link; `Gamma(link="log")`

Comment: Thank you @user20650, that helped! I also square-rooted the data and my model fits really nicely now :)

Comment: some links: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/troubleshooting.html ; https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#gamma-glmms